# How to implement SSE (Server Side Events) in SAP GW

Tags: abap

**Intro**

We got a requirement to create a web application that displays a table component, which should be refreshed after a specific `DBTAB` is modified (filtered to relevant keys only).

I made a research and concluded that in order to inform the client `SSE` (Server Side Event) would fit most.

**Problem**

I implemented a simple POC in `ABAP`. However, whenever the server is responding - a connection opens, the client receives the response (header & body), but then the connection immediately closes.

**What I tried**

1. Request from our basis team to upgrade out `GW` to the latest (`SAP S/4HANA 2020` with `SAP_GWFND` 755).
2. Search Google and SAP KB for `SSE`, `Server Side Event` etc. Nothing found.
3. Creation of an `SICF` node under `default_host` named `SSE_POC`.
4. Definition of a single handler `ZCL_CA_SSE_POC`.
5. implementation of interface `IF_HTTP_EXTENSION` in class `ZCL_CA_SSE_POC`.
6. `ABAP` code:

   ```
   DATA: lo_http_server_net TYPE REF TO cl_http_server_net.
         lo_response        TYPE REF TO cl_http_response.
   lo_http_server_net ?= server. 
   lo_response        ?= lo_http_server_net->response.

   lo_response->set_header_field( name = 'Content-Type'
                                  value = 'text/event-stream' ).
   lo_response->set_header_field( name = 'Cache-Control'
                                  value = 'no-cache'          ). " just as a workaround 
   lo_response->set_header_field( name = 'Connection'
                                  value = 'keep-alive'        ). " just as a workaround

   lo_response->set_cdata( data = 'event: event\ndata:1\n\n' ).
   ```

**Debugging**

After calling my code, standard code (`HTTP_DISPATCH_REQUEST:1726`) reaches `send_response` method of `server` object.
Inside it, it reaches:

```
   system-call plugin
       id 'HTTP'              value 'sendAndReturn'
       id 'name'              value conn_name
       id 'Stateful'          value stateful
       id 'LogonTime'         value m_authentication_time
       id 'LogonMethod'       value authentication_method
       id 'AuthorizationTime' value m_authorization_time
       id 'ExecutionTime'     value m_exe_time
       id 'EventHandlerExist' value l_eventhandler_exists
       id 'MessageOut'        value c_msg
       id 'RC'                value rc.
```

After running `system-call` - the client says an `SSE` connection opened and immediately closed.

**Client code:**

```
const evtSource     = new EventSource("http://<server>/sse_poc?sap-client=<mandt>");
evtSource.onmessage = ev => console.log(ev);
evtSource.onopen    = _ => console.log("Connection Opened");
evtSource.onerror   = ev => console.log(`error${ev.eventPhase === EventSource.CLOSED ? `: "Connection Closed"` : ''}`);
```

**Chrome console:**

```
Connection Opened
Error: "Connection Closed"
Connection Opened
Error: "Connection Closed"
... <every 3 seconds new pair>
```

**Chrome network tab**

[image: Requests]

[image: Headers]

[image: EventStream]

**Postman**

[image: Body]

**Notes**

Our system is on-premise.

Comment: Would [Websockets](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/11/18/websocket-communication-using-abap-push-channels/) also work?

Comment: Hey @Jonas Wilms, thanks for your response, `APC`/`ws` would work. However, for a one-way server-to-client notification, `SSE` is preferred. If eventually we wouldn't be able to implement `SSE`, we will sure go with `APC`/`ws` as we done in other projects.

Comment: I doubt that ABAPs http server has support for keeping long running sessions. At least I can't find something like that in cl_http_server_net. So I guess Websockets are the way to go, as they're "natively supported"

Comment: MAybe this example is helpful https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/sds-rest-publish.html

Comment: Hey @phil soady, thanks for your response. I've never heard before about `Smart Data Streaming` and will be glad to learn something new and implement it. before I start, can you tell if it should work on on-premise?

Comment: I thought it was available with so Hana on premise too. I have not used it, so can't say more.